# Spring Security Auth using RequestBody for reading JSON

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I begginer.I use Spring Boot application for REST API. I need Frontend (Angular app) to contact Springapp to log in and get access to the database. The problem is with me, I do not know how to make Spring security logged in via JSON RequestBody???I want Authorization with JSON

Controller Content

```
@PostMapping (value = "/login-koko")
public String authPost(@RequestBody AuthDTO user) {
    System.out.println(user.getPassword());
    return "SuccessPost";
}

@GetMapping (value = "/login-koko")
public String authGet() {
    return "SuccessGet";
}
```

This implements WebMvcConfigurer

```
public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
registry.addViewController("/login-koko");
}
```

This extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
                .addFilterAt(new CustomUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login-koko").permitAll()
                .loginProcessingUrl("/login-koko").permitAll()
            .and()
                .logout().permitAll()
            .and()
                .rememberMe()
            .and()
                .cors().disable()
                .csrf().disable();
    }
```

This my filter CustomUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter

```
 @Override
public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, 
HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = request.getReader();
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }
        String parsedReq = sb.toString();
        if (parsedReq != null) {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            AuthDTO authDTO = mapper.readValue(parsedReq, AuthDTO.class);
            return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(authDTO.getUsername(), authDTO.getPassword());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        throw new InternalAuthenticationServiceException("Failed to parse authentication request body");
    }
    return null;
}
```

My login and pass

```
spring.security.user.name=qwesan
spring.security.user.password=qwesan
```

Postman
But no auth[https://sun9-71.userapi.com/impg/BpfC5xCcjIyOdkz-XSN--3pHJ-3PcoLzcx_msw/WITWaWxKuhw.jpg?size=1193x509&quality=96&sign=b80141825c9ee8d54d62a7b9419d7d45&type=album]

Why didn't work

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It seem like that you login with POST /login-koko, but the UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter's url is /login (if your custom filter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter), you are supposed to POST /login.

Comment: I'm redefining RequestMapping in WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
'                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login-koko").permitAll()
                .loginProcessingUrl("/login-koko").permitAll()'

Comment: The username and password filter itself no gets